# Unexpected for Loop error Laravel 5.3

Tags: for-loop, controller, laravel-5.3

I dont know why Im getting an error of

> FatalErrorException in AdminController.php line 43: syntax error,
>   unexpected 'for' (T_FOR)

on this line

```
$weekDays = array([]);

@for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++)
  $weekDays[] = strftime('%a', $timestamp);
   $timestamp = strtotime('+1 day', $timestamp);
@endfor
```

Can you guys help me? 
Lots of thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like it's in your controller and you are using the blade syntax, which is for templating. You need to use the standard php syntax in your controllers and other php classes:

```
$weekDays = array([]);

for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++){
  $weekDays[] = strftime('%a', $timestamp);
  $timestamp = strtotime('+1 day', $timestamp);
}
```

Comment: It solved the problem for the loop howeve I got an error again fot his part:

Comment: @foreach($weekDays as $weekDay)
      <td class="text-center">{{ $weekDay }}</td>
     @endforeach

Comment: this is the error

htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: That because you have added you first element of the array as an array, `$weekDays = array([]);` should just be: `$weekDays = [];`